NetCDF CF1.0 coordinate are not read by gdalinfo
When creating a NetCDF raster with python, the projected (UTM 19N) coordinates written following the CF-1.0 conventions (compatible with the NetCDF GDAL driver) are sometines not read/recognized by gdalinfo and therfore not properly projected in QGIS.
The issue seems to be related to the coordinates values themselves, as for some values they are correctly read by gdalinfo and projected in QGIS, while for other values, gdalinfo doesnt reconize those as coordinate variables.
The values I played with that trigger the issue are the following:
width = 7920
height = 7135

rasterio.transform.from_origin(west=541107.0, north=5438536.5, xsize=1.5, ysize=1.5)`

x = rasterio.transform.xy(transform, cols=list(range(0, width, 1)), rows=0)[0]
y = rasterio.transform.xy(transform, cols=0, rows=list(range(0, height, 1)))[1]

For which gdalinfo return:
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0, 7135.0)
Upper Right ( 7920.0,    0.0)
Lower Right ( 7920.0, 7135.0)
Center      ( 3960.0, 3567.5)

Reproductible example code with and without the issue:
import netCDF4
import numpy as np
import pyproj
import rasterio

fpath = '/D/Data/TEST/test_netcdf_cf.nc'
ds = netCDF4.Dataset(fpath, "w", format="NETCDF4")

# Coordinates read by gdalinfo
width= 8026
height= 7340

# Coordinates not read by gdalinfo
width= 7920
height= 7135

# Create an affine transformation with origin over manicouagan peninsula
# Setting the pixel size to 1 fix the issue
transform = rasterio.transform.from_origin(west=541107.0, north=5438536.5, xsize=1.5, ysize=1.5)

# using those origin coordinate also fix the bug...
# What's happening here ? somme issue with GDAL who expect a regular grid ?
#transform = rasterio.transform.from_origin(west=541107.25, north=5438536.25, xsize=1.5, ysize=1.5)

x = rasterio.transform.xy(transform, cols=list(range(0, width, 1)), rows=0)[0]
y = rasterio.transform.xy(transform, cols=0, rows=list(range(0, height, 1)))[1]

ds.createDimension('y', height)
ds.createDimension('x', width)
y_var = ds.createVariable('y', 'f4', ('y',))
x_var = ds.createVariable('x', 'f4', ('x',))

y_var[:] = y
x_var[:] = x

# Create the CF grid_mapping
grid_mapping = ds.createVariable('grid_mapping', np.int32, ())

grid_mapping.crs_wtk = cf_grid_mapping['crs_wkt']
grid_mapping.semi_major_axis = cf_grid_mapping['semi_major_axis']
grid_mapping.semi_minor_axis = cf_grid_mapping['semi_minor_axis']
grid_mapping.inverse_flattening = cf_grid_mapping['inverse_flattening']
grid_mapping.reference_ellipsoid_name = cf_grid_mapping['reference_ellipsoid_name']
grid_mapping.longitude_of_prime_meridian = cf_grid_mapping['longitude_of_prime_meridian']
grid_mapping.prime_meridian_name = cf_grid_mapping['prime_meridian_name']
grid_mapping.geographic_crs_name = cf_grid_mapping['geographic_crs_name']
grid_mapping.horizontal_datum_name = cf_grid_mapping['horizontal_datum_name']
grid_mapping.projected_crs_name = cf_grid_mapping['projected_crs_name']
grid_mapping.grid_mapping_name = cf_grid_mapping['grid_mapping_name']
grid_mapping.latitude_of_projection_origin = cf_grid_mapping['latitude_of_projection_origin']
grid_mapping.longitude_of_central_meridian = cf_grid_mapping['longitude_of_central_meridian']
grid_mapping.false_easting = cf_grid_mapping['false_easting']
grid_mapping.false_northing = cf_grid_mapping['false_northing']
grid_mapping.scale_factor_at_central_meridian = cf_grid_mapping['scale_factor_at_central_meridian']

y_var.units = 'm'
y_var.standard_name = 'projection_y_coordinate'
y_var.long_name = 'y coordinate of projection'
y_var.axis = 'Y'

x_var.units = 'm'
x_var.standard_name = 'projection_x_coordinate'
y_var.long_name = 'x coordinate of projection'
x_var.axis = 'X'

# create band dimension
ds.createDimension('band', 3)
band_var = ds.createVariable('band', 'f4', ('band',), significant_digits=2)

band_var[:] = [350.23, 460.90, 680.7]

band_var.units = 'nm'
band_var.standard_name = 'sensor_band_central_radiation_wavelength'
band_var.axis = 'B'

# Create data variable
Rrs_var = ds.createVariable(
    'Rrs',
    'i4',
    ('band', 'y', 'x',),
    fill_value=21474836,
    compression='zlib',
    complevel=1)

Rrs_var.units = 'sr-1'
Rrs_var.standard_name = 'Rrs'
Rrs_var.long_name = 'Remote sensing reflectance'

Rrs_var.grid_mapping = 'grid_mapping'

RrsData = np.random.random(size=(3, height, width))

print(ds.variables['Rrs'].shape)

ds.variables['Rrs'][0:3, 0:height, 0:width] = RrsData

ds.close()


Solved in: https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/10135.
The data type "f4" (float 32) is not accurate enough to represent the coordinates values as a regular grid of integers.
Using data type "f8" (float 64) fixed the issue.
y_var = nc_ds.createVariable("y", "f8", ("y",))
x_var = nc_ds.createVariable("x", "f8", ("x",))

Also a workaround is to add the spatial_ref and GeoTransform attributes to the grid_mapping variable (see: https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/netcdf.html#georeference)
        GT0 = 541107.0  # x coordinate of the upper-left corner of the upper-left pixel
        GT1 = 1.5  # w-e pixel resolution / pixel width.
        GT2 = 0  # row rotation (typically zero).
        GT3 = 5438536.5  # y-coordinate of the upper-left corner of the upper-left pixel.
        GT4 = 0  # column rotation (typically zero).
        GT5 = 1.5  # n-s pixel resolution / pixel height (negative value for a north-up image).

        grid_mapping.spatial_ref = cf_grid_mapping["crs_wkt"]
        grid_mapping.GeoTransform = f"{GT0} {GT1} {GT2} {GT3} {GT4} {GT5}"


I've updated the answer to demonstrate the fix. I'll leave the code as the first one is pointing to the person who actually solved the issue. I think the second one is an useful reference to the documentation.
